# "skip" renamed to "frequency" in BGE logic bricks?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

In the logic editor, there is a "skip" instead of "frequency", I want to know if this is just a name change or a function change. I needed to make a flame, I was watching a tutorial and his version had "frequency" while mine had a "skip" instead.

Comment: They are the same.

Answer (score 1):

The *frequency* parameter was only renamed to *skip* in 2.75 as documented in the [release notes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.75/BGE#Logic_Brick_Sensors).

> "Frequency" parameter is renamed to "Skip" in the Logic Brick sensors as it represents skipped frames between pulses.

It still does exactly the same thing, controls how often the logic brick can run.